# beanshell Command not found: setprop when using JMeter from command line

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

So i have some tests in Jmeter which i'm running using this command:

```
java -jar .\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t .\bin\Example-Test-Plan.jmx
```

in this test i have variable 'users' which i want to change in runtime using beanshell like this:

```
java -jar .\lib\bshclient.jar localhost 9000 .\bsh\update_parameter.bsh 200.
```

This is my update_parameter.bsh file:

```
setprop("users", args[0]);
```

When i run above things i get this:

```
Connecting to BSH server on localhost:9000
Reading responses from server ...
BeanShell 2.0b6 - by Pat Niemeyer (pat@pat.net)
bsh % // Error: EvalError: Command not found: setprop( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) : at Line: 2 : in file: <unknown file> : setprop ( "users" , args [ 0 ] )

bsh % ... disconnected from server.
```

When i run same tests using GUI the parameter updates just fine...
Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This `setprop` function is defined in [`startup.bsh` file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/extras/startup.bsh) and it looks like:

```
setprop(p,v){// set a JMeter property
print("Setting property '"+p+"' to '"+v+"'.");
JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties().setProperty(p, v);
}
```

So make sure to define `beanshell.server.file` property pointing to this `startup.bsh` file and you should be able to use this or any other shorthand declared there.

[image]

In any case you can amend your code to something like:

```
org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.setProperty("users",args[0]);
```

and it will have the same effect.

More information:

- [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)
- [How to Change JMeter´s Load During Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. For some reason it seems that JMeter wasn't able to reach startup.bsh in extras directory. My best guess is that since i'm running JMeter from main dir and not the bin dir, absolute path changes as well so it's  -Jbeanshell.server.file=.\extras\startup.bsh . And it works like a charm now, so thanks again :)